# How Kyro is being used in Spark 2.X

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, apache-spark-2.0

Could you please help to clarify the below item:

- Does Kyro used in persist RDD/Dataframe. When we select pass MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER in persist.
- In case of OFF_HEAP, Tunsten approach used or Kyro is being used.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Kyro used in persist RDD/Dataframe. When we select pass MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER in persist.

- `RDD` - yes.
- `DataFrame` / `Dataset` - no, with exception to fields already serialized using `Encoders.kryo`

> In case of OFF_HEAP, Tunsten approach used or Kyro is being used.

No.

To summarize - Kryo is never used for storage in `Dataset` API.

Comment: Could you share some reference document for the same